# How can i move Strategery InfiniteScroll "Load More" button?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, category-listing

I installed Strategery InfiniteScroll to my Magento 2 project.
The plugin provides an option to display a "load more" btn at the bottom of the listing page. 
However there's a problem.
The button spawns inside the product list (not where i want it) 
How can I move it to the parent div (.products.wrapper) ? 
This cannot be done with xml as if i write inside js.phtml file it prints at the bottom of the page

[image: button position]

js.phtml:

````
<?php
/**
* Strategery Infinitescroll - Magento 2 Module
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0),
* available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
*
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 Strategery Inc. (http://www.strategery.io/)
* @author Damian A. Pastorini (damian.pastorini@strategery.io)
*/
?>
<?php /** @var $block \Strategery\Infinitescroll\Block\Init */ ?>

<?php if ($block->isEnabled()) : ?>
   <?php
   $productListMode = $block->getProductListMode();
   $mode = ($productListMode == 'grid') ? $block->getSelector('items_grid') : $block->getSelector('items_list');
   ?>
   <script>
       window.iasConfig = {
           mode: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($mode); ?>',
           debug: <?php echo (int) $block->getScrollConfig('general/debug'); ?>,
           container: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSelector('content')); ?>',
           next: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSelector('next')); ?>',
           pagination: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSelector('pagination')); ?>',
           buffer: <?php echo (int) $block->getDesign('buffer_px'); ?>,
           prev: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSelector('previous')); ?>',
           text: '<?php echo $block->escapeJsQuote(__($block->getDesign('done_text'))); ?>',
           html: '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align: center;">{text}</div>',
           <?php if ($block->getLoaderImage() !== false) : ?>
           spinnerSrc: '<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getLoaderImage()); ?>',
           <?php else : ?>
           spinnerSrc: 'data:image/gif;base64,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',
           <?php endif; ?>
           spinnerHtml: '<?php echo '<div class="ias-spinner" style="text-align: center;"><img style="display:inline" src="{src}"/> '.
               $block->escapeJsQuote(__($block->getScrollConfig('design/loading_text'))).
               '</div>'; ?>',
           trigger: {
               text: '<?php echo $block->escapeJsQuote(__($block->getDesign('load_more_text'))); ?>',
               html: '<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-next" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><a>{text}</a></div>',
               textPrev: '<?php echo $block->escapeJsQuote(__($block->getDesign('load_more_text_prev'))); ?>',
               htmlPrev: '<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-prev" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><a>{text}</a></div>',
               offset: <?php echo (int) $block->getDesign('load_more_threshold'); ?>
           },
           toolbarSelector: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSelector('toolbar')); ?>',
           toolbarAction: '<?php echo $block->getDesign('hide_toolbar') ? 'hide' : 'show'; ?>',
           memoryActive: <?php echo $block->isMemoryActive() ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
       };
       require(['jquery', 'infinitescroll'], function($){
           $(function($) {
               // InfiniteScroll:
               SgyIAS.init();
           });
       });
   </script>
<?php endif ?> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was just a config, i changed wrapper and item selector in (`stores> configuration> strategery> selectors`)
all good now! :)

[image]

Comment: Where this configuration will be shown.. I don't get it.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed in the magento admin panel, path stores > configuration > strategery > selectors